# How I can convert the content of a DIV into PDF using Nreco?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a page on html call Employee and inside that I have a div called contract that I only want to convert it to pdf using the Nreco , I have looked at the documentation but nothing helps

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the NReco.PdfGenerator package via NuGet
   Code:
   Install-Package NReco.PdfGenerator
2. Use the HtmlToPdfConverter class to create an instance of the Pdf generator
   Code:
   var pdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
3. Generate the HTML string that represents the content of the DIV element
   Code:
   string divContent = "Hello World";
4. Use the GeneratePdf() method to convert the HTML string to a PDF file
   Code:
   byte[] pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GeneratePdf(divContent);
5. Write the PDF bytes to a file or stream
   Code:
   File.WriteAllBytes("output.pdf", pdfBytes);

Comment: Hi , Ayush  , I have done the steps but I find challange on step 3 , since I already have a view , but I am only looking to export one div from my html page , so I am looking to find a way to call that div only and create pdf from it.